# How can I empty a file using awk getline

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, awk, getline

How can I delete the content of a file using `getline`. The file should be refreshed in every 9th loop and the old content until the last 9th loop then it should be deleted so that the new content can be written and retrieved again..

**Script Function:**

```
     function leeren(tmpdatei){
      while(getline line < tmpdatei){
         line=""
      }
     }
```

This the function which is supposed to delete the content of a file. The function is called on every 9th loop. Logically it is okay in this sense, but the deleting the content is not working, I guess, deleting the content of a file with `getline` is not the correct way, right?

How can I then delete the content of a file at a time or in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a file from within `awk` you could use redirection:

```
echo '' | awk '{ printf("") > "file_to_delete" }'
```

#### Edit

As Kent noted, the file needs to be closed to make this work properly. The following modification should be enough:

```awk
close("file_to_delete")
printf("") > "file_to_delete"
```

Comment: i am again not in awk, i need to do it inside awk script.

Comment: Everything within the single quotes is executed by `awk`. So in your case use: `printf("") > "file_to_delete"` where "file_to_delete" is the filename of the file you want to delete, or the variable that holds the filename.

Comment: @Thor I didn't see OP's whole script. but if it like what he said, in a loop, truncate the file, then refill, then truncate again. your printf("") > "filename" would have problem. it does the truncate only once (the first time), I would make an example in my answer for that to get better code format.

Answer (score 2):

if your shell is bash, and you REALLY want to empty the file in awk: see the test below:

```
kent:/tmp$ seq 3 > a.txt
kent:/tmp$ cat a.txt
1
2
3
kent:/tmp$ awk '{system(">a.txt")}'<<<"foo"
kent:/tmp$ cat a.txt
kent:/tmp$
```

**edit**

well you could change to `awk '{system("cat /dev/null>a.txt")}'`

this system() call will start another process, in this case is "cat" to empty the file.

you can also apply awk redirection, as Thor shows in his answer.

but be carefule with awk redirection if you do it in a loop. you should close the file every time you do `printf("") > filename.` otherwise it will append everything to the file after the 1st time truncating. see the example below:

```
kent$  cat a.txt
1
2
3

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{fn="a.txt"}{
        printf ("") > fn;
        printf("refilled")>fn;
        printf("")>fn;
        printf("refilled again")>fn;
        printf("")>fn}'<<<"foo"  

kent$  cat a.txt
refilledrefilled again
```

as you see, you would expect the last line in awk (`printf("")>fn}`) to empty the file, but it didn't.

Comment: my shell is korn shell. can you please explain the ``kent:/tmp$ awk '{system(">a.txt")}'<<<"foo"`` what it does?

Comment: you mean like this: ``system("echo '' | awk '{ printf("") > "file_to_delete" }' ")`` ?

Comment: @doniyor no, you could either use system() and shell command. like cat.  `awk '{system("cat /dev/null>a.txt")}'`  or use Thor's solution, but close the file after printf("")>"file".

Comment: yeah, why it is not emptying the file in your example ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you are not able to empty a file using only awk except if you parse every line and delete it (since awk reads a file line by line).

I don't know what you want to achieve but for me the best way would be to create a bash script where you have a function that runs your awk script and another one that empties the file (using probably `sed`) and call them as many times as you want on that file.

Comment: my wish is actually to delete the file inside the awk script. so it is not possible?

Comment: No. You need to run a separate command to empty the script. You can empty it with awk as the other answers say but not during runtime (meaning that you will not be able to read and empty and write and read again inside a single awk command).

Comment: well, i am emptying one file and reading from another file. in one loop step of awk, i can go into small while loop where i emty the other file and go on with the main loop again.... is not it possible?

Comment: I guess it is possible if you follow @Kent's answer. Give it a try. I didn't knew about the system call.